# Fragment is not showing its full width and Height

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am creating a sliding menu in my android app. But at runtime none of my fragments showing their full size as set by 'match_parent'.

**this is the image : **

[image]

**and this is my code**

*Layout :*

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />
</FrameLayout>
```

*Java Code :*

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
            case R.id.nav_place_order:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new PlaceOrderPage1Fragment()).commit();
                break;

            case R.id.nav_profile:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new ProfileFragment()).commit();
                break;

            case R.id.nav_settings:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new SettingsFragment()).commit();
                break;

            case R.id.sample:
                Toast.makeText(this,"Sample",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

        }
```

Comment: how you are adding fragments in the container?

Comment: can you show you main activity's xml where you are attaching this fragment?

Comment: post the main activity code..

Comment: problem solved.. silly mistake in main activity xml..

Comment: Width and height of the `fragment_container` must match parent.

Comment: If you solved this problem mention your answer in answer section to make help others with same problem.@PrashantGujar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check your fragment `onCreateView()` method

you should inflate view like this :

```
val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_content,container, false);
return root
```

and make sure the `place_holder` which you adding your fragment to when doing fragment transaction is visible

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, YourFragment())
```

in above code make sure fragment_container is visible and has proper height and width